# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, json.net

i am currently at integration testing phase in my project and i ran into an error while trying to test an endpoint to see if my database returns some tasks.
my domain object looks like this:

```
public class Task
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")] 
        public decimal? InitialPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

My basic test code for an endpoint

```
[Fact]
        public async Task Should_return_All_Tasks_with_ok_statusCode()
        {
            client.SetFakeBearerToken((object) token);
            
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/v1/tasks");

            response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Task>>(json);
            data.Count.Should().BeGreaterThan(0);
        }
```

When i run the test i get the error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer: 64fa643f-2d35-46e7-b3f8-31fa673d719b. Path '[0].id', line 1, position 45.
```

I have also tried using the ReadAsAsync<List>() method from the webapi.client package and i still get the same error.

an api call to the endpoint im trying to test would give:

```
[
  {
    "id": "64fa643f-2d35-46e7-b3f8-31fa673d719b",
    "title": "Garden Trimming in Lagos Ajah",
    "description": "Please my garden needs trimmin, Im in lagos",
    "initialPrice": 20.3
  }
]
```

I would appreciate the help

Comment: I have some code running the latest version of Newtonsoft (12) and it deserializes Guids just fine.  Are you using an older version of NS perhaps?

Comment: i can't see anything immediately wrong with your code, it looks like it should work just fine. it may be a bug in Json.NET:
https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/1187

Comment: @BryanLewis hi, Thanks for your input, Yes i am running the latest version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You named your `Task` class the same as the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` object in the .Net framework. The `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` has an `int` Id property. Your code to deserialize is actually trying to deserialize your JSON into the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` object.

To fix this you need to either rename your `Task` class, which I would recommend, or specify the full name to your `Task` object, including the namespace, in your line of code that's calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

Comment: You sir are a god send. That was exactly what was wrong!. i feel so dumb now. Thanks alot for this

Comment: Glad to help, and you are not the first to make this mistake.

Comment: Really great spot @quaabaam :)

Comment: I've actually named a class Task before run into similar weird issues.  I should have realized this.  Good call quaabaam.